# jQuery get all from options in array

Tags: arrays, forms

I am using this code to get all form options to array:

```
var map = {}
form.find(":input[name]").each(function() {
      var field = $(this), v = field.val(), key = field.attr("name")
     if(!isEmpty(v)){
         console.log(key,v)
         map[key] = v;
    }

});
```

The problem is then I have an array like this in the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]">
```

then is gets mutiple values for same key like this:

```
foo[] thumb
foo[] title
foo[] description
```

so it overwrites all values except the last one.

How could I store array values into comma separated string? (without targeting with exact key)